# Select optimal columns that sum up to a value while minimizing another

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have a grid of predictions from a machine-learning model. I would like to select the optimal set of predictions that follow 3 criteria.

1. The `id` column cannot be repeated
2. The sum of column `x` needs to be as close to the `x_goal` as possible
3. Each value of `y` should be minimized

#### Example Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(10)

x_goal = 20

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(1,10,20), 
                   'y':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                   'id':list(range(0,4)) * 5})

df.head(10)
```

```
          x         y  id
0  7.941886  0.542544   0
1  1.186768  0.142170   1
2  6.702834  0.373341   2
3  7.739235  0.674134   3
4  5.486563  0.441833   0
5  3.023170  0.434014   1
6  2.782566  0.617767   2
7  7.844776  0.513138   3
8  2.521998  0.650397   0
9  1.795058  0.601039   1
```

#### Example Output

In this example I achieved the 1st and 3rd criteria. But the sum is 24 when I would like it to be as close to 20 as possible.

```py
opt_1 = df.sort_values(['id', 'y']).groupby('id').first()

print(opt_1['x'].sum())
opt_1
```

```
24.455267105201795

           x         y
id
0   7.495798  0.113984
1   1.186768  0.142170
2   9.259967  0.046896
3   6.512735  0.300700
```

So far I have tried randomly selecting rows and then checking if it matches the `x_goal` but this was slow and not guarantee to find the optimal set.

Any suggestions or help is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret this is:

- Select at most one row for each id
- Such that we optimize the following two objectives:

1. the sum of the selected x values should be as close to 20 as possible
2. the sum of the selected y values should be as small as possible.

This is a multi-objective problem. So one way is to introduce two weights that determine the trade-off between these two objectives.

We can formulate the following MIP model:

```
min w1*absv + w2*ysum
subject to
   xsum = sum(i, df.x[i]*select[i])
   ysum = sum(i, df.y[i]*select[i])
   sum(i, select[i]) <= 1  for each id
   -absv <= xsum - 20 <= absv
   select[i] ∈ {0,1}
```

Here is some Python code to play with:

```
import pulp as lp

n = df.shape[0] # number of rows in data frame
w = [0.9, 0.1] # weights on objectives
xtarget = 20
K = max(df.id)

prob = lp.LpProblem("SelectRows", lp.LpMinimize)

select = [lp.LpVariable("select{}".format(i),cat=lp.LpBinary) for i in range(n)] 
absv = lp.LpVariable("absv")
ysum = lp.LpVariable("ysum")
xsum = lp.LpVariable("xsum")

prob += w[0]*absv + w[1]*ysum

prob += ysum == lp.lpSum([df.y[i]*select[i] for i in range(n)])
prob += xsum == lp.lpSum([df.x[i]*select[i] for i in range(n)])
prob += -absv <= xsum-20
prob += xsum-20 <= absv
for k in range(K+1):
    prob += lp.lpSum([select[i] for i in range(n) if df.id[i]==k]) <= 1

prob.solve(lp.PULP_CBC_CMD())
print("Status:", lp.LpStatus[prob.status])

print("xsum:{}".format(xsum.value()))
print("ysum:{}".format(ysum.value()))

df["select"] = [round(select[i].value()) for i in range(n)]
```

The output looks like:

```
Status: Optimal
xsum:20.027275
ysum:0.71071352
```

The selected rows are:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is it only selected 3 of the 4 ids. There is no `id == 0`. Still familiarizing myself with pulp so I am not sure where to fix this.

Comment: That is allowed on purpose. It obeys "The id column cannot be repeated".

Comment: It cannot be repeated but there should be a row for each id. If you look at my *Example Output* there is a row for each id `[0,1,2,3]`. In your output there is only a row for `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Indeed. As per the spec. Of course, fixing this is just a question of changing a <= 1 into ==1 in the model.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!